# How to JPA join from child element

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to select elements via JPA query/criteriaQuery but can't quite figure out how to do it.

I'm using H2 as the DB. The query i've tested in H2 console is:

```
SELECT element.* 
FROM element LEFT JOIN group_element ON element.id  = group_element.elements_id
WHERE group_id IS NULL
```

In other words i want to select groupless elements.

Classes are:

```
@Entity
class Element{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
}

@Entity
class Group{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Element> elements;
}
```

I've had no problem doing this in similar cases where "elements" were mapped by field in Element, but in this specific case i can't add that field. I can't quite figure out how to join the entities in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQL joins are from owner to owned. To get the groupless elements you could do

```
SELECT e FROM Element e WHERE e NOT IN (SELECT e2 FROM Group g INNER JOIN g.elements e2)
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the job.